# How do I find strange characters in $PATH (Mac)

Tags: macos, path, homebrew

I've been having trouble getting homebrew to work properly on my Mac. This has been an issue since I upgraded from a 2012 Mac to a 2021 (M1 Chip).

When I run `brew -help` or any homebrew command I get:

```
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `block in parse'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `each'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `flat_map'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `parse'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:124:in `new'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:124:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
    from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

With `echo $PATH` I get:

`/Users/myUserName/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:??K-:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

The `/sbin:??K-` portion of my $PATH seems strange. I can't seem to find where this is getting added to my path.

Comment: `grep "??K"  ~/.*  /etc/paths.d/*` maybe?

Comment: Another problem is that the `~/.dotnet/tools` part is wrong -- the `~` should be expanded to `/Users/myUserName` before it's added to the `PATH` variable, so there's probably some incorrect quoting or something.

Comment: @GordonDavisson can I just delete the dotnet file? I dont use dotnet, but i'm not usre that is the proper way to remove it form my computer.

Comment: The way to remove that Microsoft dotnet *"stuff"* from your Mac depends how you installed it.

Comment: @wawaloo_17 Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

When logged into **Terminal.app** (or **iTerm3**), your path is set by your login shell. Apple has changed around the login shell a couple times. So run this command to open any and all you have:

```
% open .profile ; open .cshrc ; open .zshrc; open .login; open .bash_profile
The file /Users/risner/.zshrc does not exist.
The file /Users/risner/.login does not exist.
```

Ignore any "does not exist" errors. You should have a couple files open.

You should see "set path =" for **.cshrc** or **.login** and "PATH=" for others.

Modify them to remove the paths you wish to delete. Keep in mind the `:` in between separate path elements is important. Don't make two back to back (`::`) and always have one between different paths.

> The /sbin:??K- portion of my $PATH seems strange. I can't seem to find where this is getting added to my path.

In this case it is two paths:

- /sbin
- ??K-

The ?? are very likely control characters, UTF, or Unicode characters. Not literal question marks.